# Missing fonts when building/running Appcelerator app from XCode

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I've recently updated from Titanium w/3.5.0.GA SDK to Appcelerator Studio w/5.2.0SDK and can no longer build and run the appc (5.1.0 CLI) generated projects in XCode (7.2.1) without losing the ability to display my custom font resources (app/assets/fonts).

When building a project for iOS in studio (latest 4.4.0) and deploying to connected iPhone 6 (running 9.2) all fonts appear correctly in app.  However when building and running the `<projectname>.xcodeproject` that is generated by appc during this process the same fonts do not show?

Is this related to https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818 ? Is there any fix on the horizon if so?

I have always relied on modifying the generated projects to include other asset catalogs and manually alter the build and version numbers prior to appstore submission so am very curious to find a solution to this issue - all help much appreciated!

FYI - for reference, I've tried to build the same project generated in Titanium studio w/3.5.0.GA within the Latest XCode (7.2.1) as above and the fonts still work correctly so this issue seems to be with Appcelerator Studio with CLI 5.1.0 and SDK 5.2.0 combination.

Comment: Also tried this test project : http://get.fokkezb.nl/_/3pEyEXR   Built in studio the image shows on device, then build in XCode directly image does not show on device

Comment: ^ If you have further detail to add, please edit your question, rather than adding addendums in the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this below two steps. This is a workaround, might work for you.

Step 1: Grab resource files from debug ipa:

```
a. Build a debug version for your iPhone device.
b. After the app has successfully launched on your iPhone, navigate to the ipa file in the debug build folder. Click right on the file (or cmd-click) and choose to uncompress the file
c. In the extracted archive find the payload file. Also right click on the file (or cmd-click) and choose to show its contents.
d. You should now see your resource files and folders. Select all the required files and folders and copy them in some new folder.
```

Step 2: Add files to XCode project

```
a. Open the build XCode project with XCode
b. In the left column right click (or cmd-click) on your project
c. Choose "Add Files to [project name]"
d. In the file dialog multiselect your files and folders you copied from the debug ipa in step 1
e. That's it. Now archive your product and submit it.
```

Comment: Thanks Sharif - This approach works ok, but it's not ideal to have to workaround like this.  I did find that also other assets were missing such as settings bundles etc...  in the XCode build

Comment: It's not ideal indeed, which is why it has been reported as a bug to be fixed. See https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I'd really appreciate an informed update on this?  I've just tested both 5.3.0 and 5.3.1 and am still missing the fonts and other assets :( I really need a fix or to understand if this is simply not a critical issue for Appcelerator folks as I'll need to work out another approach v. soon!!!

Comment: @miniman42 I no longer work at AppC. Please see the JIRA ticket and ask for updates there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Life Saver.